# Angular-nvD3: real time updating chart causes high CPU load

Tags: angularjs, angular-nvd3

I noticed that the example for a real time updating graph (go to http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart -> examples -> Other examples in Plunker -> "Real-time chart updating") causes a quite high CPU load for the Chrome process on my MacBook, around 50%.

I think this is quite high - is there any optimization potential? Is there any way around this issue? Reason is that my web app became less responsive after I played with a real time updating graph and I suspect that the framework isn't suitable for my needs.

Comment: I have the same issue running Angular NVD3 using a 'Microsoft Surface'. It consumes upwards of 50% CPU. This is particularly troublesome when trying to run other higher priority CPU intensive processes. My guess is that since the SVG gets re-rendered after  every update it has to consume that much more CPU. Is there any way to update part of the graph at least?